# Layout is different with same css file which I linked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

CSS file is working differently on different pages, Why?

I've linked a css file to style all my pages, but it's working differently on some pages, it's kind of changing the layout look on my new login.php page, but it's working fine with index.php page, I don't seem to understand the logic of error.

I'm putting below the codes for all pages I've described above.

The file below is header.php which I'm including in every page of mine

```
<?php 
if (!isset($layout_context))
    {
        $layout_context = "public";
    }
 ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Widget Corp <?php if ($layout_context == "admin") { echo "Admin"; } ?></title>
    <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Widget Corp <?php if ($layout_context == "admin") { echo "Admin"; } ?></h1>
</div>
```

And the code below is the CSS file itself by the name of public.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* 
#EEE489 - Light Tan
#8D0D19 - Burgundy
#1A446C - Blue Grey
#D4E6F4 - Very Light Blue
#689DC1 - Light Blue
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*/

body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #EEE489;
}

img
{
    border: none;
}

a
{
    color: #8D0D19;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1A446C;
}

#header
{
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: #1A446C;
    color: #D4E6F4;
}

#header h1
{
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

#main
{
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EEE4899;
    position: relative;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1A446C;
    color: #D4E6F4;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation
{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: #8D0D19;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

#navigation a
{
    color: #D4E6F4;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.subjects
{
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.pages
{
    padding-left: 2em;
    list-style: square;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.selected
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Page Content */
#page
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #EEE489;
    /*position: relative; */
}

#page h2
{
    color: #8D0D19;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

#page h3
{
    color: #8D0D19;
}

.view-content
{
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}


div.message
{
    border: 2px solid #8D0D19;
    color: #8D0D19;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

.error
{
    color: #8D0D19;
    border: 2px solid #8D0D19;
    margin = 1em 0;
    padding = 1em;
}

.error ul
{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

The code below is my index.php, which is working fine.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php") ?>
<?php $layout_context = "public"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php") ?>
<?php find_selected_page(true); ?>
<div id="main">
    <div id="navigation">
        <?php echo public_navigation($current_subject, $current_page); ?>
        <a href="new_subject.php">+ Add a subject</a>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        <?php if ($current_page) { ?> 
            <h2><?php echo htmlentities($current_page["menu_name"]); ?></h2>
            <?php echo nl2br(htmlentities($current_page["content"])); ?>
        <?php } else { ?> 
            <p>Welcome!</p>
        <?php } ?>
        <br />
        <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php") ?>
```

The code below is the file named login.php, now I don't know what's the problem with my css stylesheet which is changing the layout.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/validation_functions.php"); ?>
<?php
    $username = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // validations
        $required_fields = array("username", "password");           
        validate_presences($required_fields);

        if (empty($errors))
            {
                // Attempt Login
                $username = $_POST["username"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];

                $found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password);

                if ($found_admin)
                {
                    // Success
                    // Mark user as logged in
                    $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["id"];
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
                    redirect_to("admin.php");
                } 
                else
                {
                    // Failure
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/Password not found.";
                }
            }       
    } 
    else
    {
    }
?>
<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
    <div id="navigation">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        <br />
        <?php echo message(); ?>
        <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>

        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">

            <p>Username:
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>Password:
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            </p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: `$layout_context`? And how different it is? Are  directives not applying, or entire layout is messed up?

Comment: Have you inspected the elements on the page the css is not working to see if the css is actually being applied there? If it's not being applied you have a problem with your reference (or file location).

Comment: Are index.php and login.php in different folders perhaps? That would cause issues when loading from the stylesheets folder.

Comment: Please explain more specifically what the problem is. Simply loading the two pages into a browser (IE11), the only difference I can immediately see is that the yellow-brown content area is wider on the login page than index - but this is due to the text boxes on login.php, which push the width out more than the "Welcome" and "Login" text on index.php

Comment: Only there's a small line space before head section and a line space above footer section.

Comment: "Only there's a small line space before head section" please explain. A screenshot perhaps? Have you looked at the generated source?

Comment: `Only there's a small line space before head section and a line space above footer section.` It's for sure CSS issue! No way it could be done by some empty line before or between PHP tags.

Comment: Mr. Forien, Please tell me CSS issue, if you can. Although Is this about some extra unused line in my public.css file?